# Android studio - How to get synced accounts and if they are enabled?

Tags: android, parameters, synchronization, account

Can we get this sync parameters on an app?

Is this the correct way to do this?

[Android - query if a sync account is checked for syncing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3318631/android-query-if-a-sync-account-is-checked-for-syncing)

Regards.

[image: Sync]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes.html#aaad):

> In Android 8.0 (API level 26), apps can no longer get access to user accounts unless the authenticator owns the accounts or the user grants that access. The `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission is no longer sufficient. To be granted access to an account, apps should either use `AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent()` or an authenticator-specific method. After getting access to accounts, an app can call `AccountManager.getAccounts()` to access them.

### Use `AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent()`

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val intent =
            AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent(
                null, null,
                listOf("com.google").toTypedArray(), null, null, null,
                null
            )
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            val accountName = data?.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME)
            val accountType = data?.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE)
            Log.d(TAG, "account name: $accountName")
            Log.d(TAG, "account type: $accountType")
            showGoogleAccountSyncStates() // exalain it later
        }
    }
}
```

after choosing a Google account from the dialog and calling `startActivityForResult`, you can call `AccountManager.getAccounts()`, `ContentResolver.getSyncAdapterTypes()`, and `ContentResolver.getSyncAutomatically()` to get account's sync states.

```kotlin
    private fun showGoogleAccountSyncStates() {
        val types = ContentResolver.getSyncAdapterTypes()
        val am = AccountManager.get(this)
        val accounts = am.accounts
        for (account in accounts) {
            for (type in types) {
                val enabled = ContentResolver.getSyncAutomatically(account, type.authority)
            }
        }
    }
```

### Use an authenticator-specific method

Request runtime permission `Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS`, and then, you can call `AccountManager.getAccounts()` directly.

[more informations](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager#PACKAGE_NAME_KEY_LEGACY_VISIBLE)

---

Other permissions you need:

- `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />`
- `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />`

---

Note that if you use `AccountManager.newChooseAccountIntent`, `AccountManager.getAccounts()` will only return the account that you chose from account list. If you use an authenticator-specific method, `AccountManager.getAccounts()` will return all Google accouts visible to the caller.